# Share cases from child account to parent

Tags: sharing, portal

I'm developing a customer portal which needs to display cases associated to  running user account. As cases are private, I just have to do the following query to get all cases for each user.

```
SELECT Id, ... FROM Case ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

Now, they also want to see cases associated to child accounts (whatever the child level). I know it can easily be done thanks to Apex, but I was wondering if they were a standard way. To be honest, I thought that as long as an account has a "Parent Account", cases were shared.

I have an account A, with two child B and C. B has 1 case created. I'm logged as an portal user from account A, and even if I copy/paste the account B case ID, I got insufficient privileges ...

Someone could help on that please ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is first create a public group and call it something like "{Company Name} Executive Portal Group" Add the Contacts from the Parent Account that you want to expose child Account Cases to to that group.

Then what you do is on the child Account or Accounts select the "Sharing" button. Add the Public Group giving them either Read Only or Read/Write Case Access.

Make sure that those particular Contacts are using an Executive Portal User Role and that their Profile has the Portal Super User checked as true.